# How do I install my Wireless Light Switch to my Basement switch that controls multiple lights?

Tags: electrical, wiring

[image: Receiver Wiring and Switch Wiring]

My basement has a few rooms and all of the lights are controlled by the light switch at the top of the steps. My goal was to buy a wireless light switch kit that has one receiver and multiple transmitters (switches) to put one in each room.

I have included a picture of the receiver and the light switch with wiring, and tried labeling them. There are three romex bundles (a,b,c) and it looks like three groups of wiring (1,2,3), not counting ground.

It's hard to see from the pic but 1 goes to the C romex. I thought that that would be power because it's a singular black wire going to the light switch whereas "a" and "b" are twisted together so I had thought that was the lights.

I tried combining white and blue of the receiver to label 3 (white bundle), red to where 1 of the light switch used to be, and black to the 2 (black bundle) is but that didn't work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Your description has you connecting the receiver's white to both "3" (white bundle) as well as "2" (black bundle) and doesn't connect the receiver's red anywhere.

Comment: Good catch! I just made an edit to revise and fix my mistake about what I connected what to.

Comment: My guess is that you had the receiver's black and red TV wing way around. I think the #2 black bundle is hot in from the panel and hot out top another room #1 single black is the switched hot to the lights in this room.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! I'm going to try again later today.

Comment: Where's the pic of how the original switch was wired?

Comment: Hi FreeMan. The right side of the picture has the original light switch dangling down. It has two black wires connected to it (looks like 4 because of the shadows)